# how to work on detected faces independently from each other? OpenCV/Processing

Tags: image, opencv, processing, face-detection

I work on a sketch, that should detect faces and give each face their own image.

what the computer does: every time the Computer detects a new face, it becomes "face 0" and gets "image 0" assigned. The result is, the numbers for all the other faces are changing and they are getting a new image assigned as well.

what I want: Every face should get its own image, without changing it, when a new face gets detected.

I hope that you understand me, despite the language barrier. It would be great, if you would help me out with this code.

---

```
import gab.opencv.*;
import processing.video.*;
import java.awt.*;


int num = 10;
PImage[] myImageArray = new PImage[num];
Capture video;
OpenCV opencv;


void setup() {

 for (int i=0; i<myImageArray.length; i++){             
  myImageArray[i] = loadImage( str(i) + ".png");
}

  size(800, 600);
  video = new Capture(this, 800/2, 600/2);
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, 800/2, 600/2);
  opencv.loadCascade(OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE);  

  video.start();
}


void draw() {
  scale(2);
  opencv.loadImage(video);

  image(video, 0, 0 );

  Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect();
  println(faces.length);                    
 faces = opencv.detect();


  for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
    println(faces[i].x + "," + faces[i].y);  
     image(myImageArray[i], faces[i].x-70, faces[i].y-60,
                  faces[i].width+80, faces[i].height+80);
  }
}


void captureEvent(Capture c) {
  c.read();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're after sounds more like face recognition than face detection.

You need to look into a face recognition algorithm such as Eigen Faces/Fisher Faces/ Local Binary Patterns (LBP) for face recognition.

Luckily there are some Processing specific resources you can check out:

- [Processing Eigenfaces](https://github.com/atduskgreg/Processing-Eigenfaces) (uses the [p-eigenface](https://code.google.com/archive/p/p-eigenface/) library)
- [Makematics Syllabus: Fall 2012 resources on Face Recognition/Eigen Faces](http://makematics.com/syllabus/2012-fall/)
- [Lamda Labs' Face Recognition API](https://lambdal.com/face-recognition-api) and [Daniel Shiffman LambdaProcessing wrapper](https://github.com/shiffman/LambdaProcessing)
  Bare in mind some libraries may be outdated and may not work with more recent versions of Processing. If that's the case try using Processing 2.2.1